# How to add buttons dynamically from a listView?

Tags: android, listview, button, custom-adapter

I have a ADD button, by clicking on that add button a list view pops out , and in every row of that listView there is a button. By clicking the button that particular row (i mean the text and image of that row) should be added to the main screen of my app as an image button.

This is  customadapter class of listView

```
public class NewsRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Activity activity;
private List<Item> items;
private Item objBean;
private int row;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public NewsRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<Item> arrayList) {
    super(act, resource, arrayList);
    this.activity = act;
    this.row = resource;
    this.items = arrayList;

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.profile)
            .showImageForEmptyUrl(R.drawable.profile).cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
        return view;

    objBean = items.get(position);

    holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtitle);
    holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);
    holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdate);
    holder.imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    holder.pbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
            holder.button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    if (holder.tvTitle != null && null != objBean.getTitle()
            && objBean.getTitle().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getTitle()));
    }
    if (holder.tvDesc != null && null != objBean.getDesc()
            && objBean.getDesc().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvDesc.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getDesc()));
    }
    if (holder.tvDate != null && null != objBean.getPubdate()
            && objBean.getPubdate().trim().length() > 0) {
        holder.tvDate.setText(Html.fromHtml(objBean.getPubdate()));
    }
    if (holder.imgView != null) {
        if (null != objBean.getLink()
                && objBean.getLink().trim().length() > 0) {
            final ProgressBar pbar = holder.pbar;

            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                    .createDefault(activity));
            imageLoader.displayImage(objBean.getLink(), holder.imgView,
                    options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted() {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    }

    return view;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvTitle, tvDesc, tvDate;
    private ImageView imgView;
    private ProgressBar pbar;

}

}
```

This list view is parsed through json, so when i add a button the button should be the first button in the layout
 So my first ques is how can i add buttons dynamically to the main screen?? 
second question
should i use GridView to show the buttons or table layout or some other??

Plzz help im new in android programming....

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `gridView` but it adds child elements in columns first then rows. If you want to show your main screen in this fashion you can use it.

You can create a `listener` which will listen your click of button inside of list and add that item in an `array` which will populate your `gridView`.

Note:- use `array` in case you have less items otherwise `ArrayList` or any other data structure

Comment: what should i add to the array?? the text and the image view?? sry im really new in programming... would appreciate your help if you could..